# Version 7 and 8, different behavior of NSolve. Is it reproducible?

Tags: version-8, version-7

I noticed the following difference, and I wonder if it's a problem of my system or the results difference is actually due to the two different versions

```
oldsa = {0.29289321881345254` - 
    0.6666666666666666` Sin[0.5235987755982988` + phi] == 
   0.75` Cos[psi1], -0.7071067811865475` + h + 
    0.6666666666666666` Cos[0.5235987755982988` + phi] == 
   0.75` Sin[psi1], -0.5` + 
    0.6666666666666666` Sin[0.5235987755982988` - phi] == 
   0.75` Cos[psi2], -0.4660254037844386` + h + 
    0.6666666666666666` Cos[0.5235987755982988` - phi] == 
   0.75` Sin[psi2]}

NSolve[oldsa, {h, phi, psi1, psi2}]
```

gives solutions in Mathematica version 7, and no solution in ver. 8
Both run on Ubuntu 12.04 x64
Do you get the same resuts?

Comment: Yes, I find the same issue, it works in `ver.7` and `ver.9` yielding a list of 24 solutions and also this message : `NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>` but it does not work in `ver.8` i.e. it yields `{}`.

Comment: Haha not only that, but, in v8, if you apply the replacement rule `/. 0.5235987755982988\` -> π/6` it DOES produce a solution

Comment: Confirming. Solution in 7 on Linux and no solution in 8.0.4 on Windows.

Comment: @Artes Well, in my v8, if you define `oldsa2 = oldsa/. 0.5235987755982988\` -> π/6` (i.e. copy-paste the numerical value from within the trig functions and replace it with its symbolic equivalent), then `NSolve[oldsa, {h, phi, psi1, psi2}]` gives `{}` and `NSolve[oldsa2, {h, phi, psi1, psi2}]` gives a list of solutions of length 24!

Comment: To all the commenters, thank you guys

Comment: @gpap Indeed, there has been a wrong imput, so +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to how strange this is in version 8 where the code below has been tested.

First, observe that the numerical value within the trigonometric function (0.523599) is $ \pi/6 $:

```
0.5235987755982988`== π/6
```

gives

```
True
```

Now, as above, define the equation to solve

```
oldsa = {0.29289321881345254` - 
0.6666666666666666` Sin[0.5235987755982988` + phi] == 
0.75` Cos[psi1], -0.7071067811865475` + h + 
0.6666666666666666` Cos[0.5235987755982988` + phi] == 
0.75` Sin[psi1], -0.5` + 
0.6666666666666666` Sin[0.5235987755982988` - phi] == 
0.75` Cos[psi2], -0.4660254037844386` + h + 
0.6666666666666666` Cos[0.5235987755982988` - phi] == 
0.75` Sin[psi2]}
```

and a version of it with the numerical value of $ \pi/6 $ replaced by the symbolic `π/6`, i.e.

```
oldsaSymbolic = oldsa/. 0.5235987755982988` -> π/6
```

Indeed,

```
NSolve[oldsa, {h, phi, psi1, psi2}]
```

gives

```
{}
```

But

```
NSolve[oldsaSymbolic, {h, phi, psi1, psi2}]
```

gives 24 solutions!?!